# Pulling data from one page to populate info on another.

Tags: html, database

I'm trying to create a database.  Lets say a car dealership end of day they will pull out excel and delete and type things like make models years and miles so they don't have to know html.

I would like to create a page that pulls the data from the excel doc. Lets say each car has a page and there is the inventory page that has all the cars.  Both could pull from the database to populate all the fields and all they would have to do is swap pictures and keep database up to date.

My questions:

1. Should I set each page to pull from the database?
2. How do I pull that data?  Use Javascript or something else?

Comment: here is a basic idea of what the pages will look like you can kinda guess what data will be pulled
the inventory page:
http://www.dennydotson.com/newandusedcars.aspx
the car page:
http://www.dennydotson.com/newandusedcars/8770/1838597/781f0068-f2aa-4430-b9cc-539b9f0ea0f6/none/2006-Audi-A4-Johnstown-OH-43031.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd skip the spreadsheet and go with a database.  It's more flexible and faster.

Second, JavaScript basically can't read files from your computer.  You'll need a server-side technology like PHP to set this up and generate the pages you need.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little broad of a question, but I'll try to hit a few things:

```
2. How do I pull that data? Use Javascript or something else?
```

Well I don't believe you can pull excel data directly from javascript as that would be a security breach to be able to access files directly with javascript.  However you can use ajax to communicate with something like php, asp, etc that can read the excel file for you, and then send the data to your javascript in the background so it looks like the javascript is pulling it.

```
1. Should I set each page to pull from the database?
```

That's depending on how exactly you want the page to work.  A database driven page can be more dynamic, but that might be an extra layer you don't really want/need if you explicitly want the user to be able to only edit with an excel file.

If it's a pretty basic excel sheet, just mostly to keep it in a grid, you could always make a webpage that acts somewhat like an excel sheet's basic functionality for user input of their cars' makes/models/pics etc...